# Trying to impletment a Slide-In Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im new to front end development and currently trying to implement a Slide in Sidebar-snippet into my layout.

I think there is something wrong with the JS, since I have no clue about JS its hard to tell though. I know that its a lot to ask for but id appreciate some guidance.

HTML:

```
<div class="st-container">
    <nav class="st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu-1"> <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <ul>
                <li><a class="icon icon-data" href="#">Data Management</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon icon-location" href="#">Location</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon icon-study" href="#">Study</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Collections</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon icon-wallet" href="#">Credits</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav> <!-- End of Sidebar Menü -->
    <div class="navigation"> <!--Navigation-->
        <div id="st-trigger-effects" class="section">
            <button data-effect="st-effect-1"><i class="fa fa-bars"></button></i></li> <!-- Hamburger Button -->
        </div>
        <div class="nav-content section">
            <div class="nav-logo">Blogger</div>
            <div class="nav-btn"><button class="wrt-btn">Schreib' einen Artikel</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-right section">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: auto;">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: auto;">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--End of Navigation / Header-->
```

CSS:

```
.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;  
    position: fixed; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-style: normal; 
    line-height: 1.6; 
    min-height: 65px; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 500;
}
.section, li, .nav-logo, .nav-btn {
    display:inline-block;
}

#st-trigger-effects, .nav-right {
    width: 21%;
}

.nav-content { 
    width: 55%;
}

.nav-btn {
    text-align: right; 
}

.nav-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-logo, .nav-btn {
    width: 49.3%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#st-trigger-effects button {
    margin-left: 35px;
}
/******************************************
Slide in Bar
*******************************************/

.st-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #48a770;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.st-menu::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.st-menu-open .st-menu::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
}

/* content style of sidebar */

.fa.fa-bars {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.st-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.st-menu h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.st-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1.2em;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: #f3efe0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.st-menu ul li:first-child a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.st-menu ul li a:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: #fff;
}

/* Effect 1: Slide in on top */

.st-effect-1.st-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu-open .st-effect-1.st-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Classie.js

```
*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Modernizer.Custom.js

```
;window.Modernizr=function(a,b,c){function z(a){j.cssText=a}function A(a,b){return z(m.join(a+";")+(b||""))}function B(a,b){return typeof a===b}function C(a,b){return!!~(""+a).indexOf(b)}function D(a,b){for(var d in a){var e=a[d];if(!C(e,"-")&&j[e]!==c)return b=="pfx"?e:!0}return!1}function E(a,b,d){for(var e in a){var f=b[a[e]];if(f!==c)return d===!1?a[e]:B(f,"function")?f.bind(d||b):f}return!1}function F(a,b,c){var d=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.slice(1),e=(a+" "+o.join(d+" ")+d).split(" ");return B(b,"string")||B(b,"undefined")?D(e,b):(e=(a+" "+p.join(d+" ")+d).split(" "),E(e,b,c))}var d="2.6.2",e={},f=!0,g=b.documentElement,h="modernizr",i=b.createElement(h),j=i.style,k,l={}.toString,m=" -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- ".split(" "),n="Webkit Moz O ms",o=n.split(" "),p=n.toLowerCase().split(" "),q={},r={},s={},t=[],u=t.slice,v,w=function(a,c,d,e){var f,i,j,k,l=b.createElement("div"),m=b.body,n=m||b.createElement("body");if(parseInt(d,10))while(d--)j=b.createElement("div"),j.id=e?e[d]:h+(d+1),l.appendChild(j);return f=["&#173;",'<style id="s',h,'">',a,"</style>"].join(""),l.id=h,(m?l:n).innerHTML+=f,n.appendChild(l),m||(n.style.background="",n.style.overflow="hidden",k=g.style.overflow,g.style.overflow="hidden",g.appendChild(n)),i=c(l,a),m?l.parentNode.removeChild(l):(n.parentNode.removeChild(n),g.style.overflow=k),!!i},x={}.hasOwnProperty,y;!B(x,"undefined")&&!B(x.call,"undefined")?y=function(a,b){return x.call(a,b)}:y=function(a,b){return b in a&&B(a.constructor.prototype[b],"undefined")},Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(b){var c=this;if(typeof c!="function")throw new TypeError;var d=u.call(arguments,1),e=function(){if(this instanceof e){var a=function(){};a.prototype=c.prototype;var f=new a,g=c.apply(f,d.concat(u.call(arguments)));return Object(g)===g?g:f}return c.apply(b,d.concat(u.call(arguments)))};return e}),q.csstransforms3d=function(){var a=!!F("perspective");return a&&"webkitPerspective"in g.style&&w("@media (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){#modernizr{left:9px;position:absolute;height:3px;}}",function(b,c){a=b.offsetLeft===9&&b.offsetHeight===3}),a};for(var G in q)y(q,G)&&(v=G.toLowerCase(),e[v]=q[G](),t.push((e[v]?"":"no-")+v));return e.addTest=function(a,b){if(typeof a=="object")for(var d in a)y(a,d)&&e.addTest(d,a[d]);else{a=a.toLowerCase();if(e[a]!==c)return e;b=typeof b=="function"?b():b,typeof f!="undefined"&&f&&(g.className+=" "+(b?"":"no-")+a),e[a]=b}return e},z(""),i=k=null,function(a,b){function k(a,b){var c=a.createElement("p"),d=a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||a.documentElement;return c.innerHTML="x<style>"+b+"</style>",d.insertBefore(c.lastChild,d.firstChild)}function l(){var a=r.elements;return typeof a=="string"?a.split(" "):a}function m(a){var b=i[a[g]];return b||(b={},h++,a[g]=h,i[h]=b),b}function n(a,c,f){c||(c=b);if(j)return c.createElement(a);f||(f=m(c));var g;return f.cache[a]?g=f.cache[a].cloneNode():e.test(a)?g=(f.cache[a]=f.createElem(a)).cloneNode():g=f.createElem(a),g.canHaveChildren&&!d.test(a)?f.frag.appendChild(g):g}function o(a,c){a||(a=b);if(j)return a.createDocumentFragment();c=c||m(a);var d=c.frag.cloneNode(),e=0,f=l(),g=f.length;for(;e<g;e++)d.createElement(f[e]);return d}function p(a,b){b.cache||(b.cache={},b.createElem=a.createElement,b.createFrag=a.createDocumentFragment,b.frag=b.createFrag()),a.createElement=function(c){return r.shivMethods?n(c,a,b):b.createElem(c)},a.createDocumentFragment=Function("h,f","return function(){var n=f.cloneNode(),c=n.createElement;h.shivMethods&&("+l().join().replace(/\w+/g,function(a){return b.createElem(a),b.frag.createElement(a),'c("'+a+'")'})+");return n}")(r,b.frag)}function q(a){a||(a=b);var c=m(a);return r.shivCSS&&!f&&!c.hasCSS&&(c.hasCSS=!!k(a,"article,aside,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}")),j||p(a,c),a}var c=a.html5||{},d=/^<|^(?:button|map|select|textarea|object|iframe|option|optgroup)$/i,e=/^(?:a|b|code|div|fieldset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|i|label|li|ol|p|q|span|strong|style|table|tbody|td|th|tr|ul)$/i,f,g="_html5shiv",h=0,i={},j;(function(){try{var a=b.createElement("a");a.innerHTML="<xyz></xyz>",f="hidden"in a,j=a.childNodes.length==1||function(){b.createElement("a");var a=b.createDocumentFragment();return typeof a.cloneNode=="undefined"||typeof a.createDocumentFragment=="undefined"||typeof a.createElement=="undefined"}()}catch(c){f=!0,j=!0}})();var r={elements:c.elements||"abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark meter nav output progress section summary time video",shivCSS:c.shivCSS!==!1,supportsUnknownElements:j,shivMethods:c.shivMethods!==!1,type:"default",shivDocument:q,createElement:n,createDocumentFragment:o};a.html5=r,q(b)}(this,b),e._version=d,e._prefixes=m,e._domPrefixes=p,e._cssomPrefixes=o,e.testProp=function(a){return D([a])},e.testAllProps=F,e.testStyles=w,g.className=g.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1$2")+(f?" js "+t.join(" "):""),e}(this,this.document),function(a,b,c){function d(a){return"[object Function]"==o.call(a)}function e(a){return"string"==typeof a}function f(){}function g(a){return!a||"loaded"==a||"complete"==a||"uninitialized"==a}function h(){var a=p.shift();q=1,a?a.t?m(function(){("c"==a.t?B.injectCss:B.injectJs)(a.s,0,a.a,a.x,a.e,1)},0):(a(),h()):q=0}function i(a,c,d,e,f,i,j){function k(b){if(!o&&g(l.readyState)&&(u.r=o=1,!q&&h(),l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=null,b)){"img"!=a&&m(function(){t.removeChild(l)},50);for(var d in y[c])y[c].hasOwnProperty(d)&&y[c][d].onload()}}var j=j||B.errorTimeout,l=b.createElement(a),o=0,r=0,u={t:d,s:c,e:f,a:i,x:j};1===y[c]&&(r=1,y[c]=[]),"object"==a?l.data=c:(l.src=c,l.type=a),l.width=l.height="0",l.onerror=l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=function(){k.call(this,r)},p.splice(e,0,u),"img"!=a&&(r||2===y[c]?(t.insertBefore(l,s?null:n),m(k,j)):y[c].push(l))}function j(a,b,c,d,f){return q=0,b=b||"j",e(a)?i("c"==b?v:u,a,b,this.i++,c,d,f):(p.splice(this.i++,0,a),1==p.length&&h()),this}function k(){var a=B;return a.loader={load:j,i:0},a}var l=b.documentElement,m=a.setTimeout,n=b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],o={}.toString,p=[],q=0,r="MozAppearance"in l.style,s=r&&!!b.createRange().compareNode,t=s?l:n.parentNode,l=a.opera&&"[object Opera]"==o.call(a.opera),l=!!b.attachEvent&&!l,u=r?"object":l?"script":"img",v=l?"script":u,w=Array.isArray||function(a){return"[object Array]"==o.call(a)},x=[],y={},z={timeout:function(a,b){return b.length&&(a.timeout=b[0]),a}},A,B;B=function(a){function b(a){var a=a.split("!"),b=x.length,c=a.pop(),d=a.length,c={url:c,origUrl:c,prefixes:a},e,f,g;for(f=0;f<d;f++)g=a[f].split("="),(e=z[g.shift()])&&(c=e(c,g));for(f=0;f<b;f++)c=x[f](c);return c}function g(a,e,f,g,h){var i=b(a),j=i.autoCallback;i.url.split(".").pop().split("?").shift(),i.bypass||(e&&(e=d(e)?e:e[a]||e[g]||e[a.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]]),i.instead?i.instead(a,e,f,g,h):(y[i.url]?i.noexec=!0:y[i.url]=1,f.load(i.url,i.forceCSS||!i.forceJS&&"css"==i.url.split(".").pop().split("?").shift()?"c":c,i.noexec,i.attrs,i.timeout),(d(e)||d(j))&&f.load(function(){k(),e&&e(i.origUrl,h,g),j&&j(i.origUrl,h,g),y[i.url]=2})))}function h(a,b){function c(a,c){if(a){if(e(a))c||(j=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments);k.apply(this,a),l()}),g(a,j,b,0,h);else if(Object(a)===a)for(n in m=function(){var b=0,c;for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&b++;return b}(),a)a.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(!c&&!--m&&(d(j)?j=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments);k.apply(this,a),l()}:j[n]=function(a){return function(){var b=[].slice.call(arguments);a&&a.apply(this,b),l()}}(k[n])),g(a[n],j,b,n,h))}else!c&&l()}var h=!!a.test,i=a.load||a.both,j=a.callback||f,k=j,l=a.complete||f,m,n;c(h?a.yep:a.nope,!!i),i&&c(i)}var i,j,l=this.yepnope.loader;if(e(a))g(a,0,l,0);else if(w(a))for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)j=a[i],e(j)?g(j,0,l,0):w(j)?B(j):Object(j)===j&&h(j,l);else Object(a)===a&&h(a,l)},B.addPrefix=function(a,b){z[a]=b},B.addFilter=function(a){x.push(a)},B.errorTimeout=1e4,null==b.readyState&&b.addEventListener&&(b.readyState="loading",b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",A=function(){b.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",A,0),b.readyState="complete"},0)),a.yepnope=k(),a.yepnope.executeStack=h,a.yepnope.injectJs=function(a,c,d,e,i,j){var k=b.createElement("script"),l,o,e=e||B.errorTimeout;k.src=a;for(o in d)k.setAttribute(o,d[o]);c=j?h:c||f,k.onreadystatechange=k.onload=function(){!l&&g(k.readyState)&&(l=1,c(),k.onload=k.onreadystatechange=null)},m(function(){l||(l=1,c(1))},e),i?k.onload():n.parentNode.insertBefore(k,n)},a.yepnope.injectCss=function(a,c,d,e,g,i){var e=b.createElement("link"),j,c=i?h:c||f;e.href=a,e.rel="stylesheet",e.type="text/css";for(j in d)e.setAttribute(j,d[j]);g||(n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n),m(c,0))}}(this,document),Modernizr.load=function(){yepnope.apply(window,[].slice.call(arguments,0))};
```

SidebarEffects.js

```
var SidebarMenuEffects = (function() {

    function hasParentClass( e, classname ) {
        if(e === document) return false;
        if( classie.has( e, classname ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return e.parentNode && hasParentClass( e.parentNode, classname );
    }

    // http://coveroverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
        return check;
    }

    function init() {

        var container = document.getElementById( 'st-container' ),
            buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#st-trigger-effects > button' ) ),
            // event type (if mobile use touch events)
            eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
            resetMenu = function() {
                classie.remove( container, 'st-menu-open' );
            },
            bodyClickFn = function(evt) {
                if( !hasParentClass( evt.target, 'st-menu' ) ) {
                    resetMenu();
                    document.removeEventListener( eventtype, bodyClickFn );
                }
            };

        buttons.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            var effect = el.getAttribute( 'data-effect' );

            el.addEventListener( eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                container.className = 'st-container'; // clear
                classie.add( container, effect );
                setTimeout( function() {
                    classie.add( container, 'st-menu-open' );
                }, 25 );
                document.addEventListener( eventtype, bodyClickFn );
            });
        } );

    }

    init();

    })();
```

The JS files have been called in the HTML. Again, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle, so that we can test and try to help you?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s8ex2avv/   I hope i did it right

Answer (score 1):

Okay firstly,

you are trying to get an `id` of an element which doesn't have an `id` called `st-container`

Change this:

```
<div class="st-container">
var container = document.getElementById( 'st-container' )
```

Into this:

```
<div id="st-container" class="st-container">
var container = document.getElementById( 'st-container' )
```

You can now use the button to make the side bar appear, this will make it appear under all your content at the moment.

[**JSFiddle for example**](https://jsfiddle.net/s8ex2avv/2/)

### Update to come:

[**Updated JSfiddle to show menu above content**](https://jsfiddle.net/s8ex2avv/5/)

Comment: it appears under the top navigation element but thats ok since its fixed anyways. i have added a top margin to the ul in .st-menu so that the li elemts appear underneath the hamburger menu. is this a good way of doing that? i also added a higher z-index so it overlaps the main content on mobiel devices.

Comment: @WilliamJohn - I've added updated fiddle. Check it out :)

Comment: @WilliamJohn - No problem buddy - Also just updated the jsfiddle link to show the css for the navigation items to show underneath each other - If this is the answer. Just give it a tick :)